# Removing duplicates in dict and append list values to one key

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{'name': 'comet1', 'coordinates': [15.01234516, 10.12345612]},
{'name': 'comet2', 'coordinates': [11.45678762, 12.56789876]},
{'name': 'comet3', 'coordinates': [13.31512314, 14.68123912]},
{'name': 'comet3', 'coordinates': [10.78876782, 11.23234321]}]
```

I'm trying to remove duplicate names, and append the corresponding coordinates value to only one name. So the list can be something like

```
[{'name': 'comet1', 'coordinates': [15.01234516, 10.12345612]},
{'name': 'comet2', 'coordinates': [11.45678762, 12.56789876]},
{'name': 'comet3', 'coordinates': [13.31512314, 14.68123912, 10.78876782, 11.23234321]}]
```

The above data is obtained from an external file and restructured into this format. After using defaultdict and other methods, I am not quite sure on how to achieve this.

Here is my attempt (the logic error is in the second for loop.)

```
content = []
comets = {"name":comet_name, "coordinates":coordinates}
    content.append(comets)
new_d = {}
for x in content:
    for name in names: #names is a set containing all indivual comet names
        if x["name"] == name:
            print(x["name"])
            new_d = {"name":name, "coordinates": x["coordinates"].append(coordinates)
```

Comment: Welcome!  Normally you'll garner better results if you show us your attempts at solving your problem so we can help you fine-tune them, rather than just asking us to provide you a solution.  StackOverflow is not  code writing service.

Comment: You probably don't want that in the end because extracting useful coordinates from `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` will be more annoying than `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]`. Also you should probably use tuples for the pairs instead of lists.

Comment: Do you really want to keep the list-of-dicts structure? That's really terrible to work with. It would be much easier to use a single dict mapping from name to coordinates. Indeed, the only efficient way I can think of to do what your asking would be to create the single dict first, then use it to rebuild the list of dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use a `defaultdict` to collect the coordinates.  Something along these lines:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for comet in initiallist:
  result[comet['name']].extend(comet['coordinates'])
  # Or for a list of tuples
  result[comet['name']].append(tuple(comet['coordinates']))
```

That should produce the results you're after (as near I can tell).

Comment: Following Alex Hall's suggestion, you could tuple-ize the coordinate pairs also.

Comment: Agreed, but only if the user wants tuples.  His requested result explicity flattened, so I went with that, but I'll add the other option as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you have enough of these to process that a single pass through your source list preferable. Also, that you still want the list of dictionaries.

```
from collections import defaultdict


final_list = []
lookup_map = defaultdict(lambda : -1)
for comet in sighting_list:
    final_index = lookup_map[comet["name"]] 
    if final_index < 0:
        lookup_map[comet["name"]] = len(final_list)
        final_list.append(comet)
    else:
        final_list[final_index]["coordinates"].extend(comet["coordinates"])
```

That should give you a flattened list of coordinates per comet name in your comet_list.